# Is it undefined behavior to have your own header with the same name as a standard header?

Tags: c++

I have realized that for years I have my own header named `algorithm.h`.

I always include it with:

```
#include "algorithm.h"
```

as opposed to the inclusion of the **standard** header:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

I have never had any problems (not even warnings in gcc) with ambiguity but I wonder if it was just luck. I like the name of my header and I do not want to rename it just out of fear.

In case it is not undefined behavior, is it considered to be bad style?

Comment: They're not the same. One's `algorithm` and the other's `algorithm.h`.

Comment: @chris you're right! I never realized this. For some reason I thought that the <> takes away the extension.

Comment: Even if they were the same, I don't believe it would be undefined behavior. You'd no doubt end up breaking all sorts of other code though, as only one of them would be included.

Comment: <> searches your include dirs, "" searches the same dir as the source file.

Comment: Even if they were the same, I doubt any implementation looks for standard headers before local headers when using quotation marks. I mean one *could*, but I don't see a point.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik the difference between, for example `<iostream>` and `<iostream.h`> is that the `.h` version is from old versions of C++ where everything is in the default namespace. The `.h`-less versions are now preferred and they put everything in the `std` namespace to avoid collisions with your own names. Hence why you see so many `using namespace std;` statements in beginner programmers' codes.

Comment: @CoryNelson If you were being pedantic, the search order for both `<>` and `""` are implementation defined. However, most (all?) compilers do what you said.

Comment: @Adam, Even more than that, `<iostream.h>` has never been standard.

Comment: @chris True, it was never part of the formal standard. But the first formal standard is from 1998, about 15 years after C++ first appeared. Before then `<iostream.h>` was a de-facto standard because that's what Bjarne's original versions called it.

Comment: @CoryNelson: That is somewhat inaccurate. <> searches in "system locations", whatever that is (up to the compiler) and "" searches in the current directory _first_, in commandline-added directories _next_, and in system directories _last_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not undefined behaviour. The Standard doesn't say anything about any headers other than the ones that are part of the standard library. In fact, it even specifies (C++11, section 16.2.3 [cpp.include]) that if you were to do something like

```
#include "algorithm"
```

and the header isn't found, then it does the same thing as

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Whether having a header called `algorithm.h` is bad style is debatable. I would avoid it because it might confuse programmers with less experience in C++. However, something like `utils/algorithm.h` would be perfectly fine, if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not good style and you did get reasonably lucky.

What is happening is when you surround the file with quotes

```
#include "algorithm.h"
```

the compiler looks for the header in user-defined paths first.

When you surround the file with brackets,

```
#include <algorithm>
```

the compiler checks system folders for the header file first.

Therefore both header files get included. You do however need to watch out for overriding of variables defined in the separate header files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did they get lucky? There is absolutely no problem with OP's code.

Comment: There is no problem with the code itself but in another language there could be reference issues

Comment: Also on another planet.

Comment: I live on Mars, things are pretty whacky over here

Comment: But seriously, what is this about getting lucky? It is nonsense.